# How do you remove header on Github Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying GitHub Pages for my developer blog post, unfortunately I am having a hard time deleting the header part after choosing a theme.

Even though I already edited the `Readme.md`, the header is still there and I can't even remove or edit it. Do you have any idea on how to remove or edit it? There are only 2 files on my repositories: `Readme.md` and `_config.yml`

[image]

Comment: That depends on the theme you are using, copy theme files to your site and edit them

Comment: I just choose a theme under settings of repository. There are only 2 files on repositories. Do I need to download the whole theme then commit it to my repo?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way to modify what it shows.

Comment: I forgot to say, you don't need to commit all the theme files, you can just copy the file you modify

Comment: I see, I really don't know how it will work since there is no file on repositories where I can see the layout and other related stuffs and update it, but I will try.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found you can [customize your site CSS](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/#customizing-your-jekyll-themes-css) to hide the header by creating the file:

`/assets/css/style.scss`

```css
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";

header {
  display: none;
}
```

*This is a [closed issue](https://github.com/pages-themes/hacker/issues/14)  on Github.*

---

That said, you may want to override the HTML layout, so your site doesn't unexpectedly break.

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same issue with the default Jekyll theme (primer). I found [this closed issue very helpful](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/issues/21).

My steps to resolve with the default GitHub pages theme, based on the post linked above:

1. Add `_config.yml` in the root of the GitHub Pages repo
2. Add the following lines to `_config.yml`:

```yaml
name: luaphacim's site
title: null
```

Another workaround for this theme would be to give your page the same title as the title you specify in `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 3):

First, to customize the [Jekyll SEO Tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag), you can set the `name` of the site as an *empty string* and *nullify* the `title` itself, so that it does not appear to the right of the `title` of each page — create this file in the root of your repository:

**_config.yml**

```yaml
name: ""
title: null
```

Then, to completely remove the *header block* from your page, you can override the *default layout*. Copy the original file [`default.html`](https://github.com/pages-themes/hacker/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) to the `_layouts` folder of your repository and remove this block:

```html
<header>
  <!-- TL;DR -->
</header>
```

By default GitHub uses the [Primer theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer) — it can also be customized in the same way as other themes.

---

<sup>See also: [Editing the footer in GitHub pages jekyll's default minima theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533913/17130343)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to me is to get the templates for the layout you have chosen, add these to your repository, and update them to remove the header. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by the following steps.

1. Clone / download the [pages-themes/hacker](https://github.com/pages-themes/hacker) repository.
2. Copy the assets folder into your repository.
3. Open the `style.scss` file located under `/assets/css/style.scss` folder.
4. Add the following code into the file.

   ```
   @import "{{ site.theme }}";

   header {
       display: none;
   }
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23460#discussioncomment-3351576

To create the _layouts folder and the default.html file in that

1. Navigate to your repo
2. Click Add File
3. When it asks for the name of
   file, type `_layouts/default.html`
4. Copy in the
   https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/blob/master/_layouts/default.html
   code. Delete the lines:

```
{% if site.title and site.title != page.title %}
<h1><a href="{{ "/" | absolute_url }}">{{ site.title }}</a></h1>
{% endif %}
```

5. Commit the change (i.e. the added file)

The GitHub Actions bot will get to work and remake your page. You can watch its progress by clicking the Actions tab.