# Remove md Webpage header in github

Tags: github, markdown

I made a .md file in my GitHub repo. The site automatic added a header with the link to the repo index page. I can't find any way to remove it.The repo name is called school The webpage is on /school/ss/1
Link to the code: [Github](https://github.com/Mczty/school/blob/master/ss/1.md)

What it shows

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove header on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375765/how-do-you-remove-header-on-github-pages)

Comment: @the4kman I didn't use any theme on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Follow the "Layouts" instructions as shown on the Primer theme github site to edit website style: https://github.com/pages-themes/primer#layouts
2. Then, in your `_layouts/default.html`, remove lines 13-15 which add the title to your page

In their issues, I propose a simpler way to do this: https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/issues/21