# How do I customize Jekyll theme for a single page in GitHub pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I want to remove the [large hero header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375765/how-do-you-remove-header-on-github-pages) for a particular page inside my GitHub pages site.

I know how to [customize the themes layout](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/#customizing-your-jekyll-themes-html-layout), however I only want to customize the layout for a particular page.

Ex:

- `README.md`: the "home page" aka `/`.  I do NOT want to customize
- `credits.md`: the credits page at `/credits`. I do NOT want to customize.
- `help.md`: the help page at `/help`. I **DO** want to customize.  I want to [remove the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375765/how-do-you-remove-header-on-github-pages).

I'd like to do something like `/assets/css/help-style.scss`

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";

header {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just define a new layout for your `help.md`

1. Create a copy of the `layout` currently used by `help.md` (say, `page.html`)
2. Rename the new layout as `help.html` (path: `_layouts/help.html`)
3. Remove markup that renders the large hero header
4. Use `layout: help` in the front matter of `help.md`:

   ```
   ---
   layout: help
   ---
   ```

Comment: Thanks - for clarity how do I specify the `layout: `? Is it the 1st line of my `help.md` like: 
---
layout: help
---

Comment: Yes. Its called the front matter. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!