# Editing the footer in GitHub pages jekyll's default minima theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've followed [this tutorial and the following ones](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) to create a Github Pages website with Jekyll. Now I have the `minima` theme, but it seems to be a different version from the [official repo](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/), as the parameters in the repo's `_config.yml` don't work on mine (e.g. for the Twitter link I have a `twitter_username` parameter while the repo's `twitter` under `social_links` doesn't work).

What is weird is that in the footer I have the `title` parameter repeated twice, as it renders in both the `footer-heading` and `p-name` elements in the `index.html`. Is there any way to change what is rendered to those elements in the html?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When [github advise you to copy master files to override minima gem's files](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll#customizing-your-themes-html-layout) "*hidden files deep inside somewhere on you file system*" by copying master files, they commit a mistake because breaking changes can append.

The best way to override files on a jekyll theme (for now) is to copy gem's file to your working folder.

```
cd /you/working/jekyll
cp -R `echo "$(bundle info minima --path)/_*/"` .
cp -R "$(bundle info minima --path)/assets/" .
```

You then have everything needed to override minima in your working folder (_includes, _layouts, _sass and assets folders).

If you have a github page, you just have to commit and push to you publication branch.

Comment: Do I have to create a Jekyll folder or can I execute those commands in the working directory?

Comment: Executing those commands in your existing directory will allow you to override all current 2.5.1 minima files. Everything will be in the same place easy to work with.

Comment: Is this all that's needed for a Github Pages site? Do you have to rebuild anything, or can you just push your changes to `main`?

Comment: @ddejohn, just commit and push, everything will be build on github.

Answer (score 4):

The footer uses `site.author`. So if you add `author: <your name>` to your `_config.yml`, you will see `<your name>` in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

To customize the footer block of your page, you can override the *default* one from the theme. Copy the original file [`footer.html`](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/footer.html) to the `_includes` folder of your repository and customize it as you wish.

---

<sup>See also: [How do you remove header on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533791/17130343)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are really minimal and just editing .md files without adding theme files (i.e. relying on the default Jekyll theme GitHub Pages adds), add this to your .md file and it will remove the footer.

```
<style>
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: to which .md file?

Comment: @Papayapap default entry point is index.md